# Any chflag for files in Notification Center?

Tags: macos, notifications, automation

I would like to have a list of TODOs in a particular folder (tex files) in the [notification centre](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5362) (the one in the right upper corner which opens from the corner).

Notification Center is the one at the top right

[image]

where I want to get notifications of the tasks which I mark in my files. 
I want to communicate with the center to get alerts. 
I am not sure if this is possible.

**Example of tex file**

```
\documentclass{article}
... 
% TODO note this for the exam and improve the figure
Lorem ipsun.
```

Intuitively, it would be great if I can type in terminal

```
chflags showNotificationCenter TODO **/*.tex
```

to show TODOs of specific files in the alarm center.

**Is there any function to show those Tex-files' TODOs in Notification Center?**

Comment: I looked at this question a couple of times, but it is not clear to me what you exactly want.

Comment: @CousinCocaine I added a picture with explanation what is Notification Center and what I want.